# Speeding up Symbolic Integration of Hypercube with Implicit Region

Tags: performance-tuning, symbolic, integral-equations

Given:

```
Clear[\[Gamma], r];
ineq = r[3] + \[Gamma] r[4] > r[2] + \[Gamma] r[3] && r[2] + \[Gamma] (r[3] + r[5]) < r[3] + \[Gamma] (r[2] + r[4]);
reg = ImplicitRegion[ ineq, {{r[1], 0, 1}, {r[2], 0, 1}, {r[3], 0, 1}, {r[4], 0, 
 1}, {r[5], 0, 1}}];
Integrate[1, {r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5]} \[Element] reg, Assumptions -> {1 > \[Gamma] > 0}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

I would like to speed up the computation if possible.
Current Thoughts:

1.Remove unnecessary conditions:
 As far as I can tell, all of the piecewise conditions are unnecessary except the one corresponding to True. Using Simplify[] removes some of them, but that function is applied after the fact; not affecting the time.

2.Adding Assumptions: Gamma and r[n] are all Real and between 0 and 1. Adding any combination to Assumptions like:

```
$Assumptions = {0 < \[Gamma] < 1, \[Gamma] \[Element] Reals,   r[1] \[Element] Reals, r[2] \[Element] Reals,   r[3] \[Element] Reals, r[4] \[Element] Reals, r[5] \[Element] Reals}
```

, produces no affect on timing or the output. Another assumption is that I'm integrating over a specific region of a hypercube of n-volume = 1, though I don't know how to include this usefully.

3.Integrating without ImplicitRegion[]: I'm using this function since it allows plugging in any inequality, and it returns the region of the hypercube I'm interested in. There may be a faster way to integrate over a hypercube given an inequality, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: The default value (corresponding to `True`) is only valid for one value (`{\[Gamma] -> (1/2)*(3 - Sqrt[5])}`) in the interval {0, 1}.

Comment: How did you determine that?

Comment: See extended comment.

Answer (score 5):

This is an **extended comment** to address the conditions for which the default in the [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) applies:

```
Clear["Global`*"];

ineq = r[3] + γ r[4] > r[2] + γ r[3] && 
   r[2] + γ (r[3] + r[5]) < r[3] + γ (r[2] + r[4]);

reg = ImplicitRegion[
   ineq, {{r[1], 0, 1}, {r[2], 0, 1}, {r[3], 0, 1}, {r[4], 0, 1}, {r[5], 0, 
     1}}];

(int[γ_] = Assuming[1 > γ > 0, Integrate[1,
      {r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5]} ∈ reg] //
     Simplify]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

The three functions are

```
funcs = {int[γ][[1, 1, 1]], int[γ][[1, 2, 1]], 
  int[γ][[2]]}

(* {(-1 + 6 γ + γ^2 + 2 γ^4)/(24 γ^2), (
 12 - 28 γ + 19 γ^2 - 4 γ^3 + 2 γ^4)/(
 24 (-1 + γ)^2), -((-1 + 11 γ - 35 γ^2 + 81 γ^3 - 
   95 γ^4 + 45 γ^5 - 11 γ^6 + γ^7)/(
  24 (-1 + γ) γ^2))} *)
```

From the conditions specified in the `Piecewise`, the default value only applies for a single value in the interval {0, 1}

```
Simplify[ ! 2*γ >= 1 && 
        ! (Sqrt[5] + 2*γ < 3 || 
            (Sqrt[5] + 2*γ > 3 && 
               2*γ < 1))]

(* Sqrt[5] + 2 γ == 3 *)

sol = Solve[%, γ][[1]]

(* {γ -> 1/2 (3 - Sqrt[5])} *)
```

The first two functions are piecewise continuous at `γ == 1/2`

```
Equal @@ funcs[[1 ;; 2]] /. γ -> 1/2

(* True *)
```

The third (default) function is piecewise continuous with the second function at `γ == (3 - Sqrt[5])/2`

```
Equal @@ funcs[[2 ;; 3]] /. γ -> (3 - Sqrt[5])/2 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Looking at the individual components:

```
Show[
 Plot[funcs[[1]], {γ, 1/2, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, ColorData[97][1]}}],
 Plot[funcs[[2]], {γ, 0, 1/2},
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, ColorData[97][2]}}],
 Plot[funcs[[3]], {γ, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Lighter@ColorData[97][3]}}],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {int[1], int[0]}},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{γ, int[γ]} /. sol]}]
```

[image]