# Speeding up Integration over Implicit Region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, regions

Similar to my [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207879/speeding-up-symbolic-integration-of-hypercube-with-implicit-region), running

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ineq = (1+y+y^2) r[4]<r[2]+y (y r[1]+r[3]) && y (r[1]-r[2]-(1+y) (r[3]-r[4]))+r[4]<r[2];
reg1=ImplicitRegion[ineq,{{r[1],0,1},{r[2],0,1},{r[3],0,1},{r[4],0,1}}];
(int[y_]=Assuming[1>y>0,Integrate[1,{r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4]}\[Element]reg1]//Simplify])//AbsoluteTiming
```

Produces
$$
\left\{165.709,\frac{8 y^4+26 y^3+39 y^2+32 y+12}{24 (y+1)^2 \left(y^2+y+1\right)}\right\}
$$

Is there a way to speed this up using Implicit Region? Or is there a faster method to find integration bounds from an inequality? An explanation for why this isn't possible would also be accepted.

Comment: Integration bounds may be obtained from `Reduce[1 > y > 0 && First@reg1, {r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4]}] /. _Equal -> False`, where the `_Equal -> False` removes components of measure zero. It will also show some of the complexity. The order of the variable can matter, since you're setting up an iterated integral.

Comment: Doing that shows a hundred lines of complicated integration bounds. Is that the best we can do for this inequality?

Comment: There's an unconventional kluge that gets the result a couple of orders of magnitude faster, happy to post if you want, but it *is* a kluge that is not very generic...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using @Michael's suggestion brings the timing down about an order of magnitude. There are 120 components after using [`LogicalExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogicalExpand):

```
components = List @@ LogicalExpand[
    Reduce[1 > y > 0 && First @ reg1, {r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4]}] /. _Equal -> False
]; //AbsoluteTiming
Length[components]
```

> {6.53425, Null}
>
> 120

Computing integral over each region:

```
r1 = Assuming[
    0<y<1,
    Simplify @ Total[
        Map[
            Integrate[1, z ∈ ImplicitRegion[#, {r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4]}]]&,
            components
        ]
    ]
]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {7.24909, Null}

The result is basically the same as yours, except for a discrete set of values for`y`:

```
r1 /. s_Root :> N[s] //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \frac{8 y^4+26 y^3+39 y^2+32 y+12}{24 (y+1)^2 \left(y^2+y+1\right)} & \frac{1}{2}
>    \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)<y<0.657298\lor 0.543689<y<\frac{1}{2}
>    \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)\lor 0.657298<y<0.682328\lor 0.682328<y<0.754878\lor
>    y<0.543689\lor y>0.754878 \\
>  0 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

Comment: This is great for this specific problem, but it fails to generalize. For ineq = r[1] > r[2] , it gives infinity as opposed to 1/2 (half of a square with r[] as the axis). I'm currently trying to understand why it works here, but not in the simpler case.